# Python : Pandas DataFrame to CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I want to simply create a csv file from the constructed DataFrame so I do not have to use the internet to access the information.  The rows are the lists in the code: 'CIK' 'Ticker' 'Company' 'Sector' 'Industry'

My current code is as follows:

```
def stockStat():
    doc = pq('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')

    for heading in doc(".mw-headline:contains('S&P 500 Component Stocks')").parent("h2"):
        rows = pq(heading).next("table tr")
        cik = []
        ticker = []
        coName = []
        sector = []
        industry = []

        for row in rows:
            tds = pq(row).find("td")
            cik.append(tds.eq(7).text())
            ticker.append(tds.eq(0).text())
            coName.append(tds.eq(1).text())
            sector.append(tds.eq(3).text())
            industry.append(tds.eq(4).text())



            d = {'CIK':cik, 'Ticker' : ticker, 'Company':coName, 'Sector':sector, 'Industry':industry}

        stockData = pd.DataFrame(d)

        stockData = stockData.set_index('Ticker')



stockStat()
```

Comment: so have you tried `df.to_csv()`?

Comment: stockData.to_csv( )?  I have tried that but it finished the process and the csv doesn't show up in my IDE

Comment: yes have you tried that? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv

Comment: Are there certain parameters that I have to fill in to create the CSV?  I run the df.to_csv( ) and like I said it isn't available in my IDE

Comment: Did you check the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv it takes a path and various parameters for outputting, please have a look at that and come back if you're stuck

Comment: Maybe you are simply missing a return stockData in your function, and that is why you do not find the to_csv function in your IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EdChum already mentioned in the comments, creating a CSV out of a pandas DataFrame is done with the [DataFrame.to_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) method.

The dataframe.to_csv() method takes lots of arguments, they are all covered in the [DataFrame.to_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) method documentation. Here is a small example for you:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'mycolumn': [1,2,3,4]})
df.to_csv('~/myfile.csv')
```

After this, the myfile.csv should be available in your home directory.
If you are using windows, saving the file to 'C:\myfile.csv' should work better as a proof of concept.